# xamarin not install app(APK) second install

Tags: android, xamarin, mono

Im first run android project with xamarin.
but It was run for the first time and I got this error for the second time

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       ADB1000:  Deployment failed
    Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: FailedToSynchronizeFastDevAssemblies ---> Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Read-only file system
       at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token) in C:\A\vs2019mb-000030-1\_work\21\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Util\AggregateAsyncResult.cs:line 72
       at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPushSyncItems(IAsyncResult result) in C:\A\vs2019mb-000030-1\_work\21\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbSyncClient.cs:line 1071
       at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbClientTaskExtensions.InnerInvoke(TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs, Func`2 endMethod, IAsyncResult l) in C:\A\vs2019mb-000030-1\_work\21\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbClientTaskExtensions.cs:line 255
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<InstallAssemblies>d__117.MoveNext() in C:\A\vs2019mb-000030-1\_work\21\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 578
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<InstallAssemblies>d__117.MoveNext() in C:\A\vs2019mb-000030-1\_work\21\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 586
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<FastDevAsync>d__114.MoveNext() in C:\A\vs2019mb-000030-1\_work\21\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 478
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunAsync>d__106.MoveNext() in C:\A\vs2019mb-000030-1\_work\21\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 225
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__104.MoveNext() in C:\A\vs2019mb-000030-1\_work\21\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 119         0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem before.
I think this is a mono problem.
To fix this, I uninstalled and reinstalled the app
or

navigate to SDK root and cmd :

```
adb.exe uninstall packgename
```